# Possible problem with TexLive in Ubuntu

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, terminal-output

I was compiling documents in Ubuntu using the Terminal with TexLive-full without any issue until now. Today I performed a format in my PC and after the compiling procedure I get the following which is the first time that it appeared.

[image]

What does this mean and what can I do to fix this (if there is indeed something wrong)?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage
[
  top=0.7in,
  bottom=1.2in,
  left=0.8in,
  right=0.8in
]{geometry}

\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\setmainfont
[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
  Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\en}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}

\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}

\begin{document}

Text Here

\begin{lstlisting}

Code Here

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It means a successful compilation that produces a single page of output. Additionally, it seems like this is the first compilation of the file (or you may have erased the `.aux` file prior to compilation).

Comment: @Werner I don't mean that these is any issue with the result. What I mean is that some of the files produced after compilation now they are not created and also those messages beginning from "ABD:EveryShipout..." weren't appearing before.

Comment: Without a (minimal) file to test/examine, it is hard to answer this question.  The terminal output you are showing doesn't look particularly unusual.

Comment: Ok I will edit my question. I just noticed it because I was compiling from there all the time and after the format these messages appeared. Also as I have mentioned they are not all the files produced after compilation are created like before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can see from the terminal output is the following:

---

```
No file MSP430.aux.
```

This might be the first time you're compiling `MSP430.tex` or have erased `MSP430.aux` prior to compiling. This might be automated if you have `\nofiles` as part of your preamble.

---

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
```

A `f`ont `d`efinition file loaded as a result of loading [`tipa`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tipa) and/or [`fontenc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc) (see later).

---

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
```

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) is loaded and set to auto-detect the driver you're using/running. It detected you're running Xe(La)TeX.

---

```
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
```

Output from a (in)direct load of the [`everyshi` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi). Since version 3.00 (2001/05/15), the following forms part of the package (visible in [`everyshi.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ms/everyshi.dtx)):

```
\newcommand*{\@EveryShipout@Init}{%
   \message{ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros}%
   \let\@EveryShipout@Org@Shipout\shipout
   \let\shipout\@EveryShipout@Shipout
   }
\AtBeginDocument{\@EveryShipout@Init}
```

The above outputs a message to the terminal letting the user know that `everyshi` is updating macros `A`t the `B`eginning of the `D`ocument.

---

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
```

This loads some language-related files associated with the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings).

---

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmtt.fd) [1] (./MSP430.aux) )
```

Another `f`ont `d`efinition file for the `EU1` encoding of Latin Modern Typewriter font is loaded. Obtained by something like

```
\usepackage[EU1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

in the document preamble

A single page is also output as a result of the `[1]`, and the `MSP430.aux` file is opened and closed. Most likely created anew.

---

```
Output written on MSP430.pdf (1 page).
```

Since you're compiling with Xe(La)TeX, the output is a PDF. It's been written to `MSP430.pdf` which consists of a single page.

---

```
Transcript written on MSP430.log.
```

The entire terminal output, plus some other content, collectively referred to as the "transcript", is written to a file called `MSP430.log`.

Comment: Thank you for your  answer. The three lines above the "output written..." what does they mean?

Comment: @Adam: I've elaborated on the specifics of the terminal output. By the way, the terminal output does not resemble what is output when compiling the code example in your post.

Comment: I compiled the MWE before posting it and everything was the same! But thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I found the solution I was looking for in your answer.